# Socket taking too long to read data (BufferedReader)

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am reading ISO messages from a switch and its taking too long to read. its taking even upto two minutes to read the whole stream and the switch timesout the session if it doesnt get a reply in 8 secs. is there another way of getting the inputstream from the socket without using BufferedReader?

```
        s = new ServerSocket(8777);

        echo("Server socket created.Waiting for connection...");
        //get the connection socket
        conn = s.accept();
        echo("Connection received from " + conn.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " : " + conn.getPort());

        //3. get Input and Output streams
        out = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        //out.flush();
        System.out.println(new Date());
        //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(new Date());
        InputStream  in  = conn.getInputStream();
        message = in.readLine();
        echo("client>" + message);
        System.out.println(new Date());
```

here are the logs you can see the difference is about two minutes from the time it started reading till it output the message

```
Server socket created.Waiting for connection...
Connection received from 11.xx.xx.xx : 51639
Fri Jul 08 11:53:48 EAT 2016
Fri Jul 08 11:53:48 EAT 2016
client>ISO8583-9300004918040387042160708122130801ISO8583-    9300004918040387049160708122230802
Fri Jul 08 11:55:51 EAT 2016
```

Comment: I guess the switch does not end transmission with a newLine - thus the lag. Try to read bytes without BufferedReader. Is there a copy&paste error in the snippet? There are two `in`s declared. Should not compile.

Comment: still not working. i have tried with this code but the delay is still there
    InputStream  in  = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            //message = in.readLine();
            echo("client>" + bytes.toString());
            System.out.println(new Date());

Comment: "This method buffers the input internally, so there is no need to use a BufferedInputStream." Just plain read from the InputStream with a 'byte[] buffer' of some reasonable size.

Comment: @Fildor Where does that quotation come from?

Comment: @EJP Sorry, should have posted the source. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should be using [`read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) and detect the end of the message somehow.

I am not familiar with ISO8583, so you'll have to figure that out. Possible would be that it's a fixed length message protocol or there is a message terminator you can detect.

A typical example would be:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // Or other reasonable value

// ...

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead = 0;

// assuming you got the InputStream as "input"
while ( (bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0 ){ // -1 indicates EOF
    // read bytes are now in buffer[0..bytesRead-1]
    // analyse bytes to maybe add up multiple reads to a complete message.
}
```

I left out exception handling for brevity.

Comment: The loop condition should be `>`. You can only get zero if the buffer length is zero, and that's not a condition you want to loop on: it doesn't get you anywhere. Just a bug.

Comment: Thanks it worked i have used a ByteArrayOutputStream and its not delaying anymore. but now the problem is when i write to the stream the first time even when i flush it the next time i write the previous message is still there.
'ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
            while ( (bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) > 0 ){ 
                baos.flush();
                baos.write(bytes, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                out.println("response "+baos.toString("UTF-8"));
                System.out.println(baos.toString("UTF-8"));
                
            }'

Comment: `baos.write(bytes, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);` clear the buffer when you received a complete message and only write as many bytes as you have received. That is `baos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);` Chances are that your message completely fits into the buffer, then it probably will not be spread across 2 or more read cycles. If you can be sure that this is always the case just clear the ByteBuffer in each cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The output you posted doesn't consist of lines, so `readLine()` isn't appropriate, and you want the messages one at a time, so `IOUtils.toByteArray()` isn't appropriate either. Try, err, `read(byte[])`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess: message = in.readLine(); Waits until endofLine \n. Maybe you dont send some, or you miss to flush die sending socket/Stream.